# Rails Validation numbericality fails on form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Related/Fixed: [Ruby on Rails: Validations on Form Object are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804498/ruby-on-rails-validations-on-form-object-are-not-working)

I have the below validation..

```
validates :age, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, 
                                only_integer: true, 
                                :allow_blank => true
                              }
```

It is not required, if entered needs to be a number. I have noticed that if someone types in a word instead of a number, the field value changes to 0 after submit and passes validation. I would prefer it to be blank or the entered value.

#### Update:

Still no solution, but here is more information.

rspec test

```
   it "returns error when age is not a number" do
      params[:age] = "string"
      profile = Registration::Profile.new(user, params)
      expect(profile.valid?).to eql false
      expect(profile.errors[:age]).to include("is not a number")
    end
```

Failing Rspec Test:

```
 Registration::Profile Validations when not a number returns error when age is not a number

 Failure/Error: expect(profile.errors[:age]).to include("is not a number")
   expected [] to include "is not a number"
```

```
2.6.5 :011 > p=Registration::Profile.new(User.first,{age:"string"})

2.6.5 :013 > p.profile.attributes_before_type_cast["age"]
=> "string" 

2.6.5 :014 > p.age
=> 0

2.6.5 :015 > p.errors[:age]
=> [] 

2.6.5 :016 > p.valid?
=> true
```

#Form Object Registration:Profile:

```
module Registration
  class Profile
    include ActiveModel::Model

    validates :age, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, 
                                    only_integer: true, 
                                    :allow_blank => true
                                   }
    attr_reader :user
    
    delegate :age , :age=, to: :profile
    
    def validate!
      raise ArgumentError, "user cant be nil" if @user.blank?
    end
    
    def persisted?
      false
    end
    
    def user
      @user ||= User.new
    end
    
    def teacher
       @teacher ||= user.build_teacher
     end
      
     def profile
       @profile ||= teacher.build_profile
     end
     
    def submit(params)
      profile.attributes = params.slice(:age)
      if valid?
        profile.save!
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end 
    def self.model_name
      ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "User")
    end
    
    def initialize(user=nil, attributes={})
      validate!
      @user = user
    end
 end
end
```

#Profile Model:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true

  strip_commas_fields = %i[age]

  strip_commas_fields.each do |field|
    define_method("#{field}=".intern) do |value|
      value = value.gsub(/[\,]/, "") if value.is_a?(String) # remove ,
      self[field.intern] = value
    end
  end
end
```

The interesting thing is that if move the validation to the profile model and check p.profile.errors, I see the expected result, but not on my form object. I need to keep my validations on my form object.

Comment: You probably call `to_i` on the value somewhere and use this result instead of the original value passed in the request `params`.

Comment: Isn't there a validation that does not try to convert the value?

Comment: The validation does not change the assigned value at all. What I was saying is that you likely call `to_i` on your own somewhere (e.g. before actually setting the model attributes model or in a callback).

Comment: But in my case, the value is changing., That is the whole issue, it's odd

Comment: Show  registration/profile.rb

Comment: @Pascal, updated per request.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Also: our Profile is a bit weird, IMHO.
Use can never be nil, currently. Validation not required. Initializer kind of breaks the style usually used in Models (first argument is a attributes hash). If you have attr_accessors, then you don't even need to do all the public_send. Are you sure this is a model? It kind of seems more like some sort of Action/Workflow.

Comment: But why is my validation failing on the form object but not when put directly on my model? I prefer to correct my code then monkey patch it. Thank you

Comment: I got rid of the workflow stuff from the initializer. You are correct, it's unnecessary.  However, I need to solve why the validations work on the model, but not the form object. What am I doing wrong? As the validations should work on both.

Answer (score 5):

If the underlying column in the DB is a numeric type, then Rails castes the value. I assume this is done in [ActiveRecord::Type::Integer#cast_value][1]

```
def cast_value(value)
  value.to_i rescue nil
end
```

Assuming `model` is a ActiveRecord model where `age` is a integer column:

```
irb(main):008:0> model.age = "something"
=> "something"
irb(main):009:0> model.age
=> 0
irb(main):010:0>
```

This is because submitting a form will always submit key value pairs, where the keys values are strings.
No matter if your DB column is a number, boolean, date, ...

It has nothing to do with the validation itself.

You can access the value before the type cast like so:

```
irb(main):012:0> model.attributes_before_type_cast["age"]
=> "something"
```

If your requirements dictate another behaviour you could do something like this:

```
def age_as_string=(value)
  @age_as_string = value
  self.age = value
end

def age_as_string
  @age_as_string
end
```

And then use `age_as_string` in your form (or whatever). You can also add validations for this attribute, e.g.:

```
validates :age_as_string, format: {with: /\d+/, message: "Only numbers"}
```

You could also add a custom type:

```
class StrictIntegerType < ActiveRecord::Type::Integer
  def cast(value)
    return super(value) if value.kind_of?(Numeric)
    return super(value) if value && value.match?(/\d+/)
  end
end
```

And use it in your ActiveRecord class through the "Attributes API":

```
attribute :age, :strict_integer
```

This will keep the `age` attribute `nil` if the value you are trying to assign is invalid.

ActiveRecord::Type.register(:strict_integer, StrictIntegerType)
[1]: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fbe2433be6e052a1acac63c7faf287c52ed3c5ba/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/integer.rb#L34

Comment: Yes, active record, that seems to be what's happening. What would my modal look like using before_type_cast to return the original value?

Comment: Modal? Can you explain?

Comment: I meant to say model, not modal

Comment: okay, i see:-)

`attributes_before_type_cast["age"]` will give you access to it. But what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @Pascal Thank you, I ended up adding a JQuery input mask

Comment: @Pascal, I am actually getting a different result. My validation passes. I will update

Comment: What is causing the validation to fail in the form object but not the actual modal?

Comment: @Pascal, thank you for all the help. See the related post that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add validations in frontend? You can use `<input type="number" />` instead of `<input type="text" />`, which will only accept number from the user. The way I see you explaining the issue, this is a problem to be resolved in the frontend rather than backend.

You can read more about it here: [Number Type Input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp#:%7E:text=The%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22number,specifies%20the%20minimum%20value%20allowed)

Please let me know if this doesn't work for you, I will be glad to help you.

Comment: I added a JS mask for the inputs.

Comment: It's great that you have solved the problem. Congratulations!
Could you add what you did as an answer? It could help other developers. Cheers!

Comment: Front end validations can help the user experience, but should not be used as a substitute for server side validation. There are often other ways data can enter your system (imports, rake tasks, etc)

Comment: I will add my front-end,but agree, back end still needs a good solution